# Automatically sending email reminders about pending approvals

Tags: workflow, approval-process

I can not find any reference to this being a possibility.

Is it possible in SalesForce to have an Approval process time out and a reminder (they don't approve it or approve it within few days) cause a reminder email to be sent to those that approval is being waited upon from? Also is it possible to Lock the whole opportunity including Notes & Attachments(So nobody can add any notes or attachments after submitting for Approval)

Comment: This is mostly doable if upon entry to the approval process, you set two custom fields on the object being approved - `is_in_approval_process__c` (boolean) and `entered_approval_process_date__c`.  Then you can use normal time-based workflows to send email alerts. When the record leaves the approval process, reset both fields to false/null. Email will need to go to an email field on the record being approved. Multi-step approval processes would require a scheduled apex job

Comment: @crop1645 Thanks for the respond, I found this solution online  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187156&language=en_US

Comment: glad you found this -- more or less what I suggested

Comment: @crop1645 I know thank you very much, I am just new at this. Your comment was  too smart for me :P would you be able to look at this question too Please ? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66912/approval-process-lock-the-whole-opportunity-including-notes-and-attachment

Comment: @crop1645 quick question , when I make the workflow rule,  my worksheet will not send an initial email anymore. so I have a worksheet that with every change of Stage the user needs to do a "submission for approval" and everytime they do it it suppose to send an email to a manager and ask them to approve it now , when I add the Workflow rule , it doesnt send an email for approval anymore , I have two email .
Approval Assignment Email Template New Request For Approval
Approval Post Template Your Approval

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just follow the link below and create a trigger for your workflow rule 
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000187156&language=en_US

This help article does not achieve the described goal - you can't send the reminder email to the users in the active approval process, unless you knew them in advance or used additional code, not declarative options.