# Approval Process : Lock the whole Opportunity Including Notes and Attachment

Tags: opportunity, approval-process, pageblock

Currently I have an approval process, that locks the opportunity and the record but the user, still can submit **Notes & Attachments** after. Is there a way to lock those as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see there is an [Idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrJ3AAK) for this.

What you can do however is the following:

1. Add a custom field to your object called `is_locked__c`.
2. Upon entry to the approval process, use a field update to set the value to true
3. Upon exit (approved,rejected,revoked), use a field update to set to false
4. Write a before insert trigger on `Attachment` that interrogates the parentId via SOQL to see if the parent object is locked. If yes, use addError to prevent attachment for insertion. Do the same for `Note`.

No. 4 isn't the best user interface as what you might want is to disable the actual Attach a File button. This is harder as you'll need to use a VF page and a custom component that replicates the Notes and Attachments related list + buttons.

You might want to revisit the requirement to see if you can tolerate notes and attachments added while a record is in an approval process

The trigger would look something like this

```
trigger AttachmentVerification on Attachment (before insert) {
  Set<ID> oParentIdSet = new Set<ID>();

  // Step  1 - get list of parent Oppo ids
  for (Attachment a : Trigger.new)
    if (a.parentId.getSobjectType().getDescribe().getName() == 'Opportunity')
      oParentIdSet.add(a.parentId);  // only attachments under Oppos are interesting

  // Step 2 - Get those Oppos, if any 
  Map<ID,Opportunity> oIdToOppoMap = new Map<ID,Opportunity> (
     [select id, is_locked__c from Opportunity where id IN: oParentIdSet]);

  // Step 3, revisit Attachments to see if any parents are locked
  for (Attachment a: Trigger.new)
    if (oIdToOppoMap.containsKey(a.parentid) && oIdToOppoMap.get(a.parentId).is_locked__c)
     a.addError('You can\'t add an attachment to an Opportunity in an approval process');   
}
```

Comment: I love your answer, I just dont know how to do number 4 yet. if I am doing opportunity what field am I using Marketing_Material_Request__c

Comment: Oh wow thank you very much, so this basically says , if the opportunity is in Pending mode, and the Is_locked_c = true, then "You cant add an attachment .."

Comment: not sure what you mean by 'pending' but if the approval process entry criteria set is_locked__c to true and reset to false upon exit from approval process, then the attachment can't be uploaded

Comment: I think I got it , Ill do these and if something happened Ill message again , if you don't mind @crop1645

Comment: Do I just add the trigger from here, or Do I need to create VF Page and component to? @crop1645

Comment: the trigger will prevent the attachment from uploading; but the upload button will still exist. Users will self-train. You'll need a test class too. Consult apex dev doc for how to write these

Comment: Sorry again,  when I type that in the trigger it gives me this error
Error: Compile Error: line breaks not allowed in string literals at line 13 column -1

Comment: I cant add that trigger to oppurtunity trigger 
trigger AttachmentVerification on Attachment (before insert) this wont work it should be on Opportunity , No?

Comment: NVM i got it lol

Comment: Can you look at this question too http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67722/creation-a-formula-field-with-boolean please ??

Comment: Eric's answer on the above sfse question is the correct one